# Select BETWEEN column values

Tags: sql, between

I'm trying to use the BETWEEN with column names instead of direct values, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 BETWEEN column2 AND column3;
```

This is returning something like 17 rows, but if i write:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 <= column2 AND column1 >= column3) OR (column1 >= column2 AND column1 <= column3)
```

i get around 600 rows..
In both cases i only get rows where column1 value is actually the middle value, but 2nd method gives me much more results, so 1st method has something wrong with it.

I suspect the problem might be on using BETWEEN clause with column names, instead of pure values, and somehow SQL is converting the column names to actual values..its strange, but can someone enlighten me please?
Thanks

Comment: Reading my question 2 years latter...Not even I can understand how I was expecting the query to work...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 BETWEEN column2 AND column3; # gives 17 rows
```

is same as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 >= column2 AND column1 <= column3) # gives 17 rows
```

Because of your addition check of

```
(column1 <= column2 AND column1 >= column3)
```

which is `OR`ed, you get additional rows.

Comment: Ha. Ok, so adding an extra column1 BETWEEN column3 AND column2 would solve it also.
Meaning that the first value on the BETWEEN clause is actually the minimum value and the second one, the maximum.
Thanks for help

Comment: I guess you didn't see my comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Between A And B` assumes that `A<B`, i.e., that the first expression in the Between, (`A`), is less than the second expression, (`B`) it does not check or execute with the opposite option.

e.g., if you put `Where 3 Between 4 And 2`  *no rows* will be returned:

or, if you write

`Select Case When 3 Between 4 and 2 then 'true' else 'false' end`

it will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for the two statements is not the same:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 <= column2 AND column1 >= column3) OR (column1 >= column2 AND column1 <= column3)
```

Has two clauses.  Remove the first and you should have the same results as your between statement.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 >= column2 AND column1 <= column3)
```