# rails: select record if current date is between two date and show in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my database I have two columns named `start_date` and `end_date`, and I want to get the entry from form my database if today date is between `start_date` and `end_date`. My current query code is as follows but it's not returning what I expect:

```
def updateMess
  @mess = MessType.find(params[:id_param])
  @today = Date.today
  @mess_current_price = MessPrice.where('mess_id = ? AND DATE(?) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date', @mess.mess_id, @today)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => { :_mess => @mess, :_mess_price => @mess_current_price } }
  end
end
```

The above `where` command generates the following query (as seen in console):

> MessPrice Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `mess_prices`.* FROM `mess_prices` WHERE (DATE('2013-07-01') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
>
> Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 3.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)

EDIT: Following is the code for my javascript which I used to set the fields in my view by using the parsed JSON data, but it is not setting the fields in my view:

```
$(document).on('click', ".mess-update-reveal", function(){
  $.post('/mess/updateMess',{id_param :$(this).attr('data-mess-id')}, function(data){
    var mess = data._mess;
    var messPrice = data._mess_price;
    console.log(data);
    $('#id_param_update_mess').val(mess.mess_id);
    $('#mess_name_update').val(mess.mess_name);
    $('#id_mess_charge_update').val(messPrice.id);
    $('#mess_breakfast_charge_update').val(messPrice.breakfast_charge);
    $('#mess_lunch_charge_update').val(messPrice.lunch_charge);
    $('#mess_dinner_charge_update').val(messPrice.dinner_charge);
    $('#mess_monthly_charge_update').val(messPrice.monthly_charge);
    $('#mess_semesterly_charge_update').val(messPrice.semesterly_charge);
    $('#mess_capacity_update').val(mess.mess_capacity);
    $('#start_date_update').val(messPrice.start_date);
    $('#end_date_update').val(messPrice.end_date);
    $('#rebate_update').val(messPrice.rebate);
  });
});
```

The result shown by `console.log(data)` is as follows:

```
Object
_mess: Object
created_at: "2013-06-26T07:16:58Z"
hostel_id: null
mess_capacity: 200
mess_id: 1
mess_name: "Mess1"
updated_at: "2013-06-29T12:08:08Z"
__proto__: Object
_mess_price: Array[1]
0: Object
breakfast_charge: 30
created_at: null
dinner_charge: 45
end_date: "2013-12-31"
id: 1
lunch_charge: 45
mess_id: 1
monthly_charge: 2000
rebate: 100
semesterly_charge: 11000
start_date: "2013-06-01"
updated_at: "2013-06-29T12:38:51Z"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Did you try trigering the query directly? Just to check if the data format is as expected

Comment: @AnkitG yes the data format is same as I have written

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Mischa i am using mysql database

Comment: @Mischa where is generating the correct code, their is no error but the code is not retrieving the result their is one entry in database with start_date = '2013-06-01' and end_date = '2013-12-31'. So it should return one result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32676/discussion-between-hiteshtr-and-mischa)

Comment: @Mischa added the complete problem description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data._mess_price` is an array, so you either have to return the first element in the array:

```
var messPrice = data._mess_price[0];
```

or make sure that `data._mess_price` is not an array by using `first` at the end of your ActiveRecord call:

```
@mess_current_price = MessPrice.where('mess_id = ? AND DATE(?) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date', @mess.mess_id, @today).first
```

There is nothing wrong with the way you're using `BETWEEN`. The query works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786649/mysql-get-record-count-between-two-date-time) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202427/select-mysql-rows-where-todays-date-is-between-two-date-columns)

```
MessPrice.where('start_date < ? AND end_date > ?', @today,  @today)
```

Syntax for [between clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) is something like following

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

where as you are using it like following

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE value BETWEEN column_name1 AND column_name2;
```

may be that is reason it is not working as you expected

Comment: This is another way of doing it, but it doesn't explain why `DATE(?) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date` doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: No, the other way around should work fine too. I just tried `DATE(?) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date` myself and it works fine.

Comment: @Mischa :- can you provide any reference link which confirms this, so that it helps everyone?

Comment: Also, Why there is -ve marking, will some one bother to comment why it's not correct before marked answer to negative?

Comment: I downvoted and left multiple comments. Reason for downvote: your claim that his "between clause" is wrong is not true. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) is the documentation for the `BETWEEN` operator on MySQL. It talks about `BETWEEN` in terms of expressions and arguments, which can be anything (including columns). Anyway, just try it out for yourself and you'll see it works fine.

Comment: @Mischa:- Sorry but i didn't get single example which states that we can use columns.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7190939/84631) and [here's another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3746859/84631) by a 115k user. And [here's](http://www.w3fools.com/) why you shouldn't use w3schools as a reference. By the way, have you tried it yet??

Comment: @Salil i already tried the solution before writing this question your solution is alternative but i am not getting the result from this code also

Answer (score 0):

You could use below gem to find the records between dates,

This gem quite easy to use and more clear [By star](https://github.com/radar/by_star) am using this gem and the API more clear and documentation also well explained.

```
MessPrice.today #take all the 2 days records
```

Here you could pass our field also `MessPrice.by_month("January", field: :updated_at)`

Please see the documentation and try it.

Answer (score -2):

Basically you want to list the Mess price rate for record if that record is available for (say)sale between start date and end date.

I have used find_by_sql for this purpose, you could improve it further:

```
MessPrice.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM mess_prices WHERE '#{Date.today}' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date")
```

Comment: Could you motive why you have to use `find_by_sql` for this instead of a normal `where`??