# insert in table with between?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Im trying to make a table with zip codes and states for Norway and since its in order I want to bulk insert instead of inserting one and one. so from 0000 to 1295 is Oslo so I tried this but is failing anyone have some solution?

```
insert into poststed (postnr, poststed) values
    (between 0000 and 1295, 'Oslo'), 
    (between 1300 and 1304, 'Sandvika');
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, postgresql...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if using this type of  `between` is supported in SQL. but I see a huge duplication in your data model. Better You think about changing it.

Your data model could look like

```
Start , End , poststed
0000  , 1295 , oslo
```

This way, you will be done within two rows, and have them indexed, if you want.. and your query can go like

`SELECT poststed FROM MYTABLE WHERE :value between MYTABLE.START AND MYTABLE.END`

Something similar to this should work. Please refer to this question for more query details - [Select BETWEEN column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746840/select-between-column-values)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a for loop? You havent specified which version of SQL you are using, let me know and I will find the right syntax, but here is roughly what you need
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/for_loop.php

Answer (score -1):

Generate automatic data **without between**:

```
-- step 1
declare @start int = 0
declare @end int = 1295

;with numcte  
AS  
(  
  SELECT @start [SEQUENCE]
  UNION all  
  SELECT [SEQUENCE] + 1 
  FROM      
  numcte WHERE [SEQUENCE] < @end 
)
INSERT into poststed (postnr, poststed) 
SELECT *,'Oslo' FROM numcte  option (maxrecursion 0)

--step 2
declare @start2 int = 1300
declare @end2    int =1304

;with numcte  
AS  
(  
  SELECT @start2 [SEQUENCE]
  UNION all  
  SELECT [SEQUENCE] + 1  
  FROM      
  numcte WHERE [SEQUENCE] < @end2 
)
INSERT into poststed (postnr, poststed) 
SELECT *,'Sandvika' FROM numcte option (maxrecursion 0)
```